# Transparent text background for blog

Tags: html

Ok, so I have a blog and I have a problem. My post background is green, but when I write on it, the TEXT BACKGROUND is WHITE.
So it's green background, white text background, and black text, it looks pretty bad..

I don't know if this has to do with anything, I'm not a programmer, but I need to see if I can change anything in the HTML coding so it doesn't look so bad...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS to your HTML text container.

`style="background-color: transparent;"`

So for example if your text is wrapped in paragraph tags, do the following `<p style="background-color: transparent;">text text text</p>`